# error: no member named 'emplace' , when compiling Liquibook using make all

Tags: c++11, makefile, emplace, mpc

```
In file included from ./Market.h:6:
In file included from 
/Users/shubhamsharma/projects/liquibook/src/book/depth_order_book.h:6:
/Users/shubhamsharma/projects/liquibook/src/book/order_book.h:559:17: 
error: no member named 'emplace' in
  'std::__1::multimap<liquibook::book::ComparablePrice,
  liquibook::book::OrderTracker<std::__1::shared_ptr<orderentry::Order> >,
  std::__1::less<liquibook::book::ComparablePrice>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const
  liquibook::book::ComparablePrice, liquibook::book::OrderTracker<std::__1::shared_ptr<orderentry::Order> > > >
  >'
  stopBids_.emplace(key, std::move(tracker));
```

I have set all the environment variables, Makefile is generated using MPC, The error comes after make all. I have tried upgrading my gcc to 4.9 but still the same error occurs. Please help!

Comment: Check the makefile and see what command is being used to compile. You have to explicitly enable C++11 features. On g++, this is done with `-std=c++11`.

Comment: main.o $(foreach lib, , $(foreach libpath, ., $(wildcard $(libpath)/lib$(lib).a))) @test -d "/Users/shubhamsharma/projects/liquibook/bin/" || mkdir -p "/Users/shubhamsharma/projects/liquibook/bin/" g++ -std=c++11 -fPIC -g -D_REENTRANT -L"." main.o -ldl $(subst lib,-l,$(sort $(basename $(notdir $(wildcard /usr/lib/librt.so /lib/librt.so))))) -lpthread -o "$@"

Comment: Above is the command generated using 'make all' still iam getting following 2 errors :  

        No member named emplace,  
        no matching function for call to 'make_shared'.